# Coherent systems on K3 surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

Does anyone know whether the theory of coherent systems on $K3$ surfaces has been studied and, if yes, can you give me a reference? In particular, is there an analogue of Gieseker stability and of Mumford stability for coherent systems on a $K3$? If yes, are there results concerning the smoothness and the dimension of the corresponding moduli spaces?

Comment: Giulia will answer your question on Facebook :)